# Cache OSM using MapProxy TMS

Tags: python, gis, openlayers, openstreetmap

For development purposes I'd like to cache OSM tiles using MapProxy in ESPG:25832, and serve those back as a proxy TMS service.

WMS/WMTS services looks fine in QGIS, but TMS is incorrect adjusted, in QGIS and OpenLayers both.

I have a config mapproxy.yaml file like so:

```
services:
  demo:
  tms:
  wmts:
  wms:
    srs: ['EPSG:25832', 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:2154','EPSG:3857']

layers:
  - name: osm
    title: Open Streetmap Tiles EPSG:25832
    sources: [osm_cache]

caches:
  osm_cache:
    grids: [osm_grid]
    meta_size: [4, 4]
    sources: [osm_cache_in]
    format: image/jpeg

  osm_cache_in:
    grids: [GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR]
    disable_storage: true
    sources: [osm_source]

sources:
  osm_source:
    type: tile
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    url: http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png

grids:
  osm_grid:
    srs: 'EPSG:25832'
    bbox: [388309.92,5265326.14,609798.17,5515636.81]
    bbox_srs: 'EPSG:25832'
    origin: 'nw'
    tile_size: [256, 256]

globals:
  cache:
    # where to store the cached images
    base_dir: '/mapproxy/cache_data'
    # where to store lockfiles
    lock_dir: '/mapproxy/cache_data'
```

My example url for adding layers into QGIS as a TMS is http://127.0.0.1:8080/tms/1.0.0/osm/EPSG25832/{z}/{x}/{-y}.jpeg

QGIS and OpenLayers force reproject that layer to EPSG:3857 and adjust its geometry far from the place that is should be - don't know why.
[image]

Comment: EPSG:25832 suggests you will have a custom tile grid, in which case  `{-y}` in the url will not work as expected in OpenLayers and you should use a tileUrlFunction.  See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_XYZ-XYZ.html

Comment: Related: there a lots of possible issues, see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383303/20340) for working TMS to TMS mapproxy cache which does not move things around